# How to combine a mosaic plot with a xyplot?

Tags: r, lattice, mosaic

I'm trying to reproduce [this plot](http://oi44.tinypic.com/295bb5t.jpg):

[image]

It looks like a xyplot in library lattice, but I couldn't find a way to combine a mosaic plot with a xyplot.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simulation of potential data:

```
    Smoker <- sample(c("yes", "no"), 100, T)
    Days <- sample(c("thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"), 100, T)
    Time <- sample(c("day", "night"), 100, T)
    Sex <- sample(c("m", "f"), 100, T)
    Value <- sample(1:10, 100, T)

    DF <- data.frame(Value, Smoker, Days, Time, Sex)
```

The plot is produced using package `vcd`:

```
    library(vcd)

    cotabplot(~ Smoker + Days + Time | Sex, data = DF, panel = cotab_mosaic, direction = "v")
```

EDIT: uploaded the plot:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 4):

You are just looking for the panel function that is built into vcd:::cotabplot

```
library(vcd)
data("alzheimer", package = "coin")
alz <- xtabs(~smoking + disease + gender, data = alzheimer)
cotabplot(~ smoking + disease | gender, data = alz, panel = cotab_coindep, n = 5000)
```

[example http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/8407/1l6d.jpg](http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/8407/1l6d.jpg)

Comment: It may also interest you to look into the different arguments "panel" takes.  Here is the help file: http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/vcd/html/cotab_panel.html